# returning javascript via ajax but it doesnt work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to get the links that appear after clicking the business name to appear in a light box. on a standalone page, it was possible but as soon as I send the same code through ajax, it does not call the light box anymore. help?

This is the original file, which is supposed to represent a 3rd party publisher site, integrating our code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="lib/js/jquery.ppo.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/sp.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>         
</head>
<body>
    This is the publisher's website. <br>
    <div id="bizname1" onclick="showComp(this.innerHTML)" id="bizname" class="bizname">click here - this event should be substituted for an 'on load'.</div><br><br>

lots of data about the company here

<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Company info will be listed here.</b></div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the ajax script, showcomp.js:

```
function showComp(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getbutton.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is the getbutton.php file called by the ajax function:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();

include('config.php');  
init_connection();

$sql=select content from db;// this part works fine, so actual sql query not inserted here.

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    $companyname = $row->result1;
    $contenturl = $row->result2;
    //echo $companyname;
    //echo $contenturl;

?>  

<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/DudfBIxw6do?iframe=true&width=640&height=390" rel="prettyPhoto" title="my caption"> Video in iframe
    <img src="images/thumb-1.jpg" width="100" height="40" alt="Video in iframe" />
    </a>
<a href="demo/vidrefer.php?iframe=true&width=500&height=410" rel="prettyPhoto" title="my caption"> Vidrefer in iframe
    <img src="images/thumb-1.jpg" width="100" height="40" alt="Vidrefer in iframe" />
</a>
<br />


</BODY>
</HTML> 

<?php
}

//echo out button here. give the button what it needs to launch the light box. 
echo "
<br>
<div id='button'>
this is a button
</div>
";
//mysql_close($con);
?>
<script id="ppready" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
</script>
```

Please help if you can see why it is not working! Thank you.

Comment: You've got a serious SQL injection issue. I would not put this on the web where just anyone could access it.

Comment: Also I don't see you using the company name result anywhere, but if you do make sure to escape it and company info because otherwise you have an XSS security issue. This is like a textbook case of how not do things if you don't want to get hacked.

Comment: Finally it would be helpful if you explained what the response was or if you're seeing any errors and if you've tried the sql query on the command line and if that returned anything.

Comment: the response is a link retrieved via $contenturl. this will then be displayed on the initial page that made the call, and when clicked should be displayed in a light box. 

The link is returned perfectly, but when i click it opens in a new window, rather than a light box as it should. 

when i try this code without the ajax call, the lightbox functionality works perfectly with a link.

Comment: It sounds like you're using some kind of javascript library or third party code that isn't working for you. Rel attributes don't have any kind of natural JavaScript hook. I recommend you check the documentation for the thing you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this! the problem was due to the fact that the javascript already acted before I loaded my new elements via ajax. all I had to do was to load my elements in before the ajax call and hey presto!

An alternative solution would have been to use live() or livequery() in jquery. They would have kept the jquery acting on elements both before and after they loaded into the DOM. Simples.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with the fix. :)

Answer (score -1):

The JS would not run on the client side, when it is just echo'ed from the server side. Try moving your codeblock

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
<-- inside--> 
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

To look like :

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you are correct. You can add script elements dynamically with innerHTML and it will execute.

Comment: Oh I dint know that. Thanks apphacker! :) .. So possibly the PHP part of it is not getting executed properly. I tried executing the code, plain vanilla without the getbutton.php, and it worked fine. So check your getbutton.php for possible errors..

Comment: The php side is working fine and returning the links fine. the only problem is that the links are not being opened in a light box, despite having the correct 'rel' tags to connect them to the javascript.